# Spectrum color picker: How can I change the position of the custom added colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spectrumjs

I am using [Spectrum color picker plugin](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/).

I am trying to change the position of the custom added colors (`sp-palette-row-selection`) over to another place? How can I edit the JavaScript to allow me to do so?

Here's a link to the full `JavaScript` code: [spectrum.js](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.js).

I think the important function were looking for (of the `JavaScript` file) is this:

```
function drawPalette() {

    var currentColor = get();

    var html = $.map(paletteArray, function (palette, i) {
        return paletteTemplate(palette, currentColor, "sp-palette-row sp-palette-row-" + i, opts);
    });

    updateSelectionPaletteFromStorage();

    if (selectionPalette) {
        html.push(paletteTemplate(getUniqueSelectionPalette(), currentColor, "sp-palette-row sp-palette-row-selection", opts));
    }

    paletteContainer.html(html.join(""));
}
```

I removed the inside of the `if-statement`, and added the following:

```
$('.sp-input-container').after($('.sp-palette-row-selection'));
```

But when I did that, I didn't see the "custom added colors" at all.